How to grep/sed through a column - the eLisp way?
I want the table formula to basically go through every data line of column $2 between the 1st and 4th hline, looking for a field width flag - in this example <14>* - and as soon as it finds it, to copy its value - in this example 14* - quit the search, and give out the result in bottom line of 2nd column.
'* Could be any number upto 3 digits, but implementing that flexibility is not the issue.
#+NAME:test-spreadsheet
I*1 |$1-------+$2--------------+$3---------|
   1| Visited | Not visited    | Locations |
   2|         | <14>           |           |
I*2 |$1-------+$2--------------+$3---------|
   3| HERE    |                | Rome      |
   4|         | HERE           | Lisboa    |
   5| HERE    |                | Stockholm |
I*3 |$1-------+$2--------------+$3---------|
   6| 2       |                | 3         |
I*4 |$1-------+$2--------------+$3---------|
   7| 67      | #ERROR         |           |
I*5 |$1-------+$2--------------+$3---------|
#+TBLFM: @7$2='(field-width-flag-tracker)

(defun field-width-flag-tracker ()
  (while (not num-bar-length)
    (mapcar
      (lambda (x)
        (if (string-match "<\\(14\\)>" x)
          (setq num-bar-length (match-string 1 x))
        )
      )
      '(@I$2..@IIII$2)
    )
  )
  (print num-bar-length)
)

So, what field @7$2 should look like: 14
What it actually looks like—as seen above: #ERROR
In other words:
How does a correct eLisp function looks like, which efficiently finds and copies the value of a field width flag of a column?

There is too much irrelevant detail here: please condense it to a simple question and make the example table as simple as possible to illustrate your question (in particular, the first three formulas are irrelevent here, right? and so are all the confusing decorations on the table).

Thanks for condensing and simplifying (although you did not go quite far enough: see my answer for how to present the table).

Please take a look at the answer and let me know if it resolves your problem. Thanks!

Here's one possible implementation (I've simplified your table and eliminated irrelevant things):
#+NAME:test-spreadsheet
|---------+-------------+-----------|
| Visited | Not visited | Locations |
|         | <14>        |           |
|---------+-------------+-----------|
| HERE    |             | Rome      |
|         | HERE        | Lisboa    |
| HERE    |             | Stockholm |
|---------+-------------+-----------|
| 2       |             | 3         |
|---------+-------------+-----------|
| 67      | 14          |           |
|---------+-------------+-----------|
#+TBLFM: @7$2='(field-width-flag-tracker  @I..@IIII)


#+begin_src elisp
  (defun field-width-flag-tracker (&rest cells)
    (let ((l (delete nil (mapcar (lambda (x) (when (string-match "<\\([0-9]+\\)>" x) (match-string 1 x))) cells))))
      (if l
          (car l)
        "")))
#+end_src

Evaluate the source block with C-c C-c to define the function and then evaluate the formula with C-c C-c.
The table formula takes the range of cells to consider and passes them as a list to the function. The function maps the anonymous lambda function across the list. The anonymous function checks if there is a match with <N>, where N is a sequence of digits from 0 to 9, and remembers the parenthesized part (i.e. just the sequence of digits). Most of the cells won't match, so we'll get a bunch of nils in the returned list which we delete. If there is something left in the list, we return the first element. Otherwise we return an empty string.
